# Can't get session variable to work in sql UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert

First page:

```html
<?php
session_start();

//db info

$conn = new mysqli("$server","$user_name","$password","$database");

$sql = "SELECT id FROM Client_Information order by id desc limit 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $id=$row['id'] + 1;
 }
}

$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$sitename = $_POST['sitename'];
$sitetype = $_POST['sitetype'];
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];
$color3 = $_POST['color3'];
$color4 = $_POST['color4'];
$sitedescription = $_POST['sitedescription'];
$aboutme = $_POST['aboutme'];
$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

if (isset($sitename) && isset($sitetype) && isset($color1) 
 && isset($color2) && isset($contactname) && isset($phone) 
 && isset($email) && isset($address) && isset($sitedescription) 
 && isset($aboutme)) { 
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Client_Information (id, sitename, sitetype, color1, color2,
          color3, color4, sitedescription, aboutme, 
          contactname, phone, email, address, timestamp)
   VALUES ('$id', '$sitename', '$sitetype', '$color1', '$color2',
     '$color3', '$color4', '$sitedescription', '$aboutme', 
     '$contactname', '$phone', '$email', '$address', 
     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    
 $conn->query($sql);

 header('Location: images.php');
}



mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Second page:

```html
<?php
session_start();


echo $_SESSION['id'];

//db info

$conn = new mysqli("$server","$user_name","$password","$database");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$wherevar = $_SESSION['id'];
$exsitename1 = $_POST['exsitename1'];
$exsitename2 = $_POST['exsitename2'];
$exsitename3 = $_POST['exsitename3'];
$exsitename4 = $_POST['exsitename4'];
$exsiteurl1 = $_POST['exsiteurl1'];
$exsiteurl2 = $_POST['exsiteurl2'];
$exsiteurl3 = $_POST['exsiteurl3'];
$exsiteurl4 = $_POST['exsiteurl4'];
$exsitedescr1 = $_POST['exsitedescr1'];
$exsitedescr2 = $_POST['exsitedescr2'];
$exsitedescr3 = $_POST['exsitedescr3'];
$exsitedescr4 = $_POST['exsitedescr4'];

if (isset($exsitename1) && isset($exsitename2) && isset($exsitename3) && isset($exsitename4)
  && isset($exsiteurl1) && isset($exsiteurl2) && isset($exsiteurl3) && isset($exsiteurl4)
  && isset($exsitedescr1) && isset($exsitedescr2) && isset($exsitedescr3) && isset($exsitedescr4)) {
 $sql =  "UPDATE Client_Information
   SET exsitename1='$exsitename1', exsitename2='$exsitename2', exsitename3='$exsitename3', 
    exsitename4='$exsitename4', exsiteurl1='$exsiteurl1', exsiteurl2='$exsiteurl2', 
    exsiteurl3='$exsiteurl3', exsiteurl4='$exsiteurl4', exsitedescr1='$exsitedescr1', 
     exsitedescr2='$exsitedescr2', exsitedescr3='$exsitedescr3', exsitedescr4='$exsitedescr4'
   WHERE id = '$wherevar'";
 
 $conn->query($sql);
 
 header('Location: index.php');
}

session_destroy();
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

So the first page works fine and inserts all the data into the db, but when the second page is ran, it doesn't update the same row that was inserted on the first page. It just leaves all those variable.
On the second page, I'm trying to have it edit the row that was just created.

Comment: print your **update** query and run on phpmyadmin

Comment: What is the flow of second page? Does it populate the form and allow to edit OR it just update automatically when control is transfer to second page?

Comment: Also Check the POST data and the condition.

Comment: You're a sitting duck for SQL Injection attacks as the user submitted data isn't validated at all, and it's not even escaped! All user submitted data should be validated and prepared statements used